# In SQL Server, can we change the Unicode replacement character from "?" to something else?

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I understand the vagaries of Unicode in SQL Server - varchar vs nvarchar, etc.  I don't have a problem storing and retrieving Unicode data.  However, there are some fields we have chosen to keep as varchar, since a non-ASCII character in those fields is considered anomalous.

When a Unicode character makes it into one of those non-Unicode fields, SQL Server converts it to a question mark:  "?".  BUT, sometimes it's hard to tell when a substitution has occurred because a question mark is a valid character in those fields.

My question:  Can I get SQL Server to use a different substitution character, rather than a question mark?  For instance, an underscore or even an empty string ('')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight answer to your question is, you can not 'set' that character. As others suggested and you probably already knew, need to check for valid data to your 'special' varchar fields.

Comment: Thanks for the straight answer.  Yes, there is no question that it should be handled better, and that's an ongoing project.  As a quick band-aid, I would just like to be able to handle it better at the point of insertion if possible... at least to be able to see for sure where substitution happened.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, any unicode character that does not have an ASCII equivalent leads to data loss when you put it into a varchar, and leaves behind a question mark:

```
select ascii(cast(nchar(1000) as varchar));
```

I agree with R. Martinho Fernandes, you need to solve this at the application layer.  You could have the app replace any 2-byte unicode pair that has value over 255 with whatever you want.  Maybe you can change your application-layer encoding to accept ASCII and Extended ASCII data only.  But trying to fault the data layer in this case is like saying, "Our data field only accepts 'M' or 'F.'  Why is the database complaining when the user sends us a 'Z'?"

Comment: Why 255? ASCII has only 128 different values.

Comment: This returns 220:  select ascii(cast(nchar(220) as varchar))  ASCII is 8 bits, AFAIK

Comment: What can I say? That is wrong. [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) is a 7-bit encoding.

Comment: Standard ASCII is 7-bit, extended ASCII is 8-bit (I looked it up ;)  .  Either way, it's only the 2nd byte of unicode that SQL Server doesn't know what to do with.  The first byte (up to 256 values) it handles fine.

Comment: There isn't *one* extended ASCII.

Comment: I agree with R. Martinho Fernandes also, it should be handled at the application layer.  To do that, I have to rewrite a bunch of VB6 apps that have lots of embedded SQL statements.  That will take some time, and I just wondered whether SQL-server had an option to use a different replacement character in the interim.

Answer (score 1):

Because I was bored. I'm near positive this won't be useful in application, but it does do what you asked for. You could create a function with this if you really wanted to...

```
Declare @Nvarchar Nvarchar(25) = N'Hɶppy',
        @NVbinary Varchar(128),
        @parse Int = 3,
        @NVunit Varchar(4),
        @result Varchar(64) = '0x',
        @SQL Nvarchar(Max);

Select  @NVbinary = master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(Convert(Varbinary(128),@Nvarchar))

While (@parse < Len(@NVbinary))
Begin
        Select  @NVunit = Substring(@NVbinary,@parse,4),
                @parse = @parse + 4


        If      Substring(@NVunit,3,2) = '00'
        Begin
                Set     @result = @result + Substring(@NVunit,1,2)
        End
        Else
        Begin
                Set     @result = @result + '22' -- 22 is the hex value for quotation mark; Use Select Convert(Varbinary(8),'"') to get the value for whatever non-unicode character you want.
        End

End

Set     @SQL = 'Select Convert(Varchar(128),' + @result + '), ''' + @result + ''''

Select  @Nvarchar, @NVbinary
Exec    sp_executeSQL @SQL
```